# Unknown syntax in React Native project using keyword "declare"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I just ran into a line of code in a react native app that looks like the following:

```
declare type Any = any;
```

Where is `declare` and `any` defined? Is this from a third party tool?

Later on, I see the `Any` type get used in the following Component definition:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  textInput: Any;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }
```

I've never seen the syntax `textInput: Any;` outside of the context of an object, eg: key/value.

Comment: Look like your are reading the code written by Typescript language

Comment: If it's using Typescript, wouldn't there would be a reference in package.json, or is that not how it works?

Comment: please ref here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links. Typescript can be installed globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking at either a TypeSript (TS) file or a file that uses Flow type notation (I tried but couldn't tell which one it is based on that short snippet). TypeScript, developed by Microsoft, is a superset of JavaScript that add type annotations (among other things) and Flow, developed by Facebook, is another kind of annotation for JS.

`declare type Any = any` means telling the TS/Flow compiler that there's a type called `Any` that can be literally anything (string, number, object, etc). `textInput: any` means all instances of `LoginForm` has a property ("field" in Java parlance) called `textInput` whose type is `Any`.

Comment: Any chance you can reference my comment above? Wouldn't Typescript or flow have to be referenced in package.json? Where can we confirm it is being used?

Comment: What's the extension of the file? If it's `ts` or `tsx`, it's TypeScript. If it's just `js` or `jsx`, most likely Flow. You don't really need to have TypeScript explicitly declared in `package.json` because the TypeScript compiler can be run from the command line using a globally installed npm package (`npm i -g typescript`). On the other hand, I think there's a good chance Flow does need to be declared in `package.json` because it's a Babel plugin.

Comment: just a .js extension, anything else would have definitely tipped me.

Comment: Most likely Flow. If you provide more code from the code base then I can provide a more conclusive answer.

Comment: I see a .flowconfig, so that has to be it, thank you :) I'll look into documentation for more information.